# Using a before_action in the index and extracting data from each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, public-activity

I think I might be missing something really obvious with this one but I just can't figure it out. I'm trying to extract the id and provider params from the parameters saved from a custom_activity event on PublicActivity and pass them to my Notification module and display the output in the view. My problem is that I can't get the info I need from each activity to be passed to Notifications. With this current setup I get all activities but I only get one set of parameters to get passed. So.. How can I set each activity id and get the needed data from them to pass to Notification::Timeline?

```
before_action :set_activity, only: :show
def show
    @activities   = PublicActivity::Activity.order(created_at: :desc).where(recipient_id: current_user.id, recipient_type: 'User')
    @post_id      = set_activity.parameters[:id] 
    @provider     = set_activity.parameters[:provider]
    notify        = Notification::Timeline.new(@post_id, @provider, current_user)
    @post_entry   = notify.construct
    @post_entry
end
private

def set_activity
    PublicActivity::Activity.where(trackable_type: 'User').find(params[:id])
end
```

My Routes

```
resources :activities
get '/notifications/:id', to: 'activities#show'
```

This is a single activity for clarity

```
<PublicActivity::Activity id: 13, trackable_id: 1, trackable_type: "User", owner_id: 1, owner_type: "User", key: "like", parameters: {:id=>"1187467057945665_1220996764592694", :provider=>"github"}, recipient_id: 1, recipient_type: "User", created_at: "2015-10-09 16:23:34", updated_at: "2015-10-09 16:23:34">
```

Also, I've tried plucking the data directly but I am unsure of how to match each id and provider value to the corresponding activity.

```
# @activities.where(trackable_type: 'User').pluck(:parameters).map do |id| {id: id[:id]} end
#  => [{:id=>"1187467057945665_1220988311260206"}, {:id=>"1231979956827708"}, {:id=>"1230071203685250"}, {:id=>"619281766889582596"}, {:id=>"1187467057945665_1220996764592694"}]
# @activities.where(trackable_type: 'User').pluck(:parameters).map do |provider| {provider: provider[:provider]} end
#  => [{:provider=>"github"}, {:provider=>"github"}, {:provider=>"github"}, {:provider=>"github"}, {:provider=>"stackoverflow"}]
```

Comment: Are you sending in an id parameter to your index action? The way you're setting the activity assumes that params[:id] is available. This may need to be a show action instead. So, are you sending in an id parameter manually?

Comment: I'm not. I'll try and put the result

Comment: If you're not providing an id parameter manually, and the route is not nested, then the provided code will never work as your set_activity function is looking up a record based on the params[:id] which will normally always be nil on the index action.

Comment: Ok. That solved one problem. I changed everything from index to show, but the problem now is that I can only load one :id. Back to the original problem how do I get each id, then get the needed id and provider and match it to the corresponding activity? My routes:   

    resources :activities
    get '/notifications/:id', to: 'activities#show'

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I changed it back to an index action and just had to set the variable in the view

```
def index
    @activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order(created_at: :desc).where(recipient_id: current_user.id, recipient_type: 'User')
end
```

In my view

```
<% @post_entry = Notification::Timeline.new(activity.parameters[:id], activity.parameters[:provider], activity.owner)%>
```